# Variável local não atribuída C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-error

Olá, estou no inicio do meu aprendizado de programação e estou tendo problemas com esse erro "uso de variável local não atribuída" no código abaixo apresenta esse erro relacionado a variável "salLiqui",eu utilizo ela no calculo de INSS normalmente, já no bloco do Imposto de renda ela quebra, mesmo ela ja sendo utilizada anteriormente no bloco do INSS.

```
using System;

namespace Valendo1
{
    class Calculo_Trabalhista
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double vHora,qHora,salBrut,inss,irpf,salLiqui,baseCalcIrpf= 0;

            string msgIrpf = "0";

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Para efetuar o calculo irei precisar que insira alguns dados.");
                Console.WriteLine("Primeiramente, qual o seu nome completo?");
                string nome = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Qual a sua profissão?");
                string prof = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Quantos dependentes você possui?");
                int qDep = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Quantas horas você trabalha por semana?");
                qHora = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Quanto recebe por hora?");
                vHora = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                switch(vHora)
                {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    default:
                        salBrut = (qHora * vHora)*4;

                        //Calcular INSS
                        if (salBrut <= 1317.07)
                        {
                            inss = salBrut * 0.08;
                            salLiqui = salBrut - inss;
                            baseCalcIrpf = salLiqui - qDep * 179.71;
                        }
                        else if (salBrut > 1317.07 && salBrut <=2195.12)
                        {
                            inss = salBrut * 0.09;
                            salLiqui = salBrut - inss;
                            baseCalcIrpf = salLiqui - qDep * 179.71;
                        }
                        else if (salBrut > 2195.12 && salBrut <= 4390.24)                       {
                            inss = salBrut * 0.12;
                            salLiqui = salBrut - inss;
                            baseCalcIrpf = salLiqui - qDep * 179.71;

                        }



                        //Calcular Imposto de Renda
                        if (salBrut <= 1787.77)
                        {
                            msgIrpf = "Sua renda não gera cobrança de IRPF!";
                        }
                        else if (salBrut> 1787.77 && salBrut <=2679.29)
                        {
                            irpf = baseCalcIrpf * 0.075;
                            salLiqui = salLiqui - irpf;

                        }
                        else if (salBrut >= 2679.30 && salBrut<= 3572.43)
                        {
                            irpf = baseCalcIrpf * 0.15;
                            salLiqui = salLiqui - irpf;
                        }
                        else if (salBrut >= 3572.44 && salBrut <=4463.81 )
                        {
                            irpf = baseCalcIrpf * 0.225;
                            salLiqui = salLiqui - irpf;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            irpf = baseCalcIrpf * 0.275;
                            salLiqui = salLiqui - irpf;
                        }




                        break;



                }


            } while (vHora != 0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Pronto, acho que assim fica melhor de visualizar, no bloco acima utilizo a mesma variavel para calcular, porem somente no bloco seguinte tenho esse retorno.

[image]

Comment: Toda a variável deve ser inicializada. Isso quer dizer que na linha double vHora... você deve por um valor em todas elas.  Você pode fazer da forma que fez e trocar as vírgulas por = que vai funcionar também. De qalquer forma, o correto seria deixar as variáveis visíveis dentro do escopo apenas que elas são necessárias

Comment: Desculpa, ainda aprendendo a usar o forum, não saiu a parte de cima do codigo
 double vHora,qHora,salBrut,inss,irpf,salLiqui,baseCalcIrpf= 0;
eu inicializei todas ela com 0, como comentei as variaveis foram utilizadas no primeiro bloco normalmente, inclusive essa do suposto erro, porem quando abri outro bloco IF ele retorna essa mensagem.

Comment: Da forma como foi declarada, somente a última varíavel foi inicializada como 0. Faça: `double vHora = qHora = salBrut = inss =irpf =salLiqui = baseCalcIrpf= 0;`

Comment: Não funcionou desse jeito sugerido, mas de fato eu precisava declarar todas 
double vHora = 0,qHora=0,salBrut=0,inss=0,irpf=0,baseCalcIrpf= 0, salLiqui = 0;
Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Tem vários outros erros no código, ele funciona, mas não está certo. Se pesquisar aqui tem muito sobre o assunto.